# Questions that are not authentic questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Sometimes, not only on philosophy stackexchange but also on other sites on the SE network, we usually have ideas that are not exactly questions to be answered, but rather topics to discuss with other members of the community.

For example, if one wants to discuss an idea or opinion he has on abortion, or the best order to study metaphysics, or a formalized ethical theory or argument one wants to bring to discussion, one tends to write their idea in a form of a question (which is not a question at all), with an ending like : what do you think about this proof? Do you have a counter-argument? is my reasoning valid and sound?

I personally think that it would be better if there is an option, where one can clearly distinguish between what is an academic question and answer, and what is a mere idea or opinion that users discuss.

Because what happens sometimes, is that a member is very enthusiastic about an idea or a "theory" he just had, and wants to share it with others so that they can discuss it, so (s)he asks a question with details of their "theory" in the description. Which I think is not an authentic question.

Comment: Stack Exchange is strictly a Q&A site though, it's not a platform for open-ended discussion. Otherwise, if the underlying topic/question is on-topic (not primarily opinion-based/too broad), then I'd suggest posting the topic *as the question* and self-answer with their own theory. (cross-site reference on Anime.SE: [How do we respond to “Is my theory right?” questions?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014))

Comment: Yes, I agree ..  still there are questions out there that are not questions in the sense of : "I do not know the answer and I came here to find out" , but in the sense of : "This is what I think, what do you think about it?".

Comment: @SmootQ: The only appropriate way to deal with this kind of demand here is asking for references that discuss similar/opposing positions since the community members' thinking or opinion really is not of any importance on StackExchange insofar it is not informed and supported by publicly available sources like e.g. published philosophical texts. Other than that, there is chat where you can discuss ideas.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Personally, I use chat rooms, thank you

Comment: They are enthusiastic and this enthusiasm can draw them into a deeper interest in philosophy. It is a complex issue. We don't want to slam the door in their face. These questions are often closed, but perhaps in the meantime they will get a helpful answer or comment.

Comment: @SmootQ "but in the sense of : 'This is what I think, what do you think about it?'" those types of questions are explicitly off topic, nobody is saying those questions don't exist, what we are saying is they are against the rules and should be closed. This is the text of the close option for those questions: "Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enough reputation to participate and create chat rooms.  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

That is the easy part. The problem might be to encourage others to participate. If you create a chat room send me a notice and I will stop by.

Comment: Thank you Frank ! :)